# How do i post a Json data into my state ReactJs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, setstate

Please help me i have this format of data on below , 
this data format is doing by another one in back-end of the app

when is empty is look like that

```
"opening_time":{"Mon":[["0"],["0"]],
"Tue":[["0"],["0"]],
"Wed":[["0"],["0"]],
"Thu":[["0"],["0"]],
"Fri":[["0"],["0"]],
"Sat":[["0"],["0"]],
"Sun":[["0"],["0"]]}
```

when i send data from my submit button i want to save data like below :

```
"opening_time":{"Mon":[["1","07:00","12:00"],["1","13:00","17:00"]],
"Tue":[["1","07:00","12:00"],["1","13:00","17:00"]],
"Wed":[["1","07:00","12:00"],["1","13:00","17:00"]],
"Thu":[["1","07:00","12:00"],["1","13:00","17:00"]],
"Fri":[["1","07:00","12:00"],["1","13:00","17:00"]],
"Sat":[["1","07:00","14:00"],["0"]],
"Sun":[["0"],["0"]]}
```

let me explain

```
"Thu":[["1","07:00","12:00"],["1","13:00","17:00"]],
```

"thu"=is the day
["1","07:00","12:00"] => first shift/
"1" is active,
"07:00" opening time of first shift,
"12:00" closing time if first shift
i have create a state as below

```
class OpeningTime extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log(props)
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      opening_time:
      {"Mon":[[""],[""]],
      "Tue":[[""],[""]],
      "Wed":[[""],[""]],
      "Thu":[[""],[""]],
      "Fri":[[""],[""]],
      "Sat":[[""],[""]],
      "Sun":[[""],[""]]} 
    }
```

i don't know how to accessed of each item of opening_time to save my data from my input onChange function , i try a lot of attempt but i don't found a solution  ,i am blocked can somebody help me please

Comment: _"i try a lot of attempt but i no one work"_ - You've missed to add one of those attempts.

Comment: @Andreas you have a solution so ?

Answer (score 0):

Create this function to update the opening time

```
updateOpeningTime = (field,val) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        let updatedOpeningTime = {...prevState.opening_time}


        updatedOpeningTime[field] = val
        return {opening_time: updatedOpeningTime}
    })
}
```

Then use it like this

```
//                                     Set day and value dynamically
onChange={() => this.updateOpeningTime('Sat',[["1","07:00","12:00"],["1","13:00","17:00"]])}
```

Hope this helps